# How to inject converting String to class in Google Guice 3.0

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I am trying Google Guice3.0 for light-weight DI. I would like to read properties and convert it to Class type and inject to a class. Here is my code.

```
setting.properties
port = 31200
handler=com.mypackage.handler.MyHandler

Module
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("setting.properties"));
            Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}

@Singleton
public class MyServer {

     @Inject @Name("port") int port;

     @Inject @Name("handler") Class<? extends BaseHandler> handlerClass; 
}

public interface BaseHanlder {
   //
}

public MyHandler implements BaseHandler {
  //
}
```

I want to convert handler property from the properties to Class and inject it into MyServer. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tries this code with guice 3.0 and it works. Do you get an error ?

Answer (score 3):

Like @gontard said, this works as Guice already contains converter for class.

It uses Class.forName(fqn) to get the Class.

You can add other custom converters using the [Pluggable Type Converters see Binder#convertToTypes](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#convertToTypes-com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher-com.google.inject.spi.TypeConverter-).

By default you have converters for all primitives types, enums and class. For implementation details you can see [here](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/TypeConverterBindingProcessor.java).

Comment: first link is broken - that's why link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow

Comment: Both links were broken. Thanks for pointing this out. Fixed now.